# Improving the speed of a line of code that uses a vector to extract a row of data

Tags: r, function, performance, for-loop

I have a for loop as follows (which is part of a function which can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69625942/improving-the-speed-function-by-identifying-the-bottle-neck-of-the-function?noredirect=1#comment123067674_69625942)):

```
People_met <- c(15L, 66L)

for (j in 1:length(People_met)) {
                # Grab who they will meet
                Meetingsa <- Data[People_met[j], ]
                # If exposed change State
                if(Meetingsa$State== "Exposed") {
                    Urand1 <- runif(1,0,1)
                    if (Urand1 < parameters$S2E){
                        Data$State[i] <-  "Exposed"
                    }   
                }
            }
```

I used `profvis` to identify that the `Meetingsa <- Data[People_met[j], ]` part of this for loop takes a very long time (the right line measures time).

[image]

I would like to speed this up, for example using `data.table`. I however actually ended up slowing it down significantly. I am not sure what else to try. Could someone explain to me what options would be faster?

## Data

```
Data <- structure(list(AgentNo = 1:100, State = c("Exposed", "Exposed", 
"Exposed", "Exposed", "Exposed", "Infected", "Infected", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", "Susceptible", 
"Susceptible", "Susceptible"), Mixing = c(0.832540284609422, 
0.0231213096994907, 0.152527641970664, 0.354236921761185, 0.237191909225658, 
0.828387739369646, 0.746136361733079, 0.578939395956695, 0.758876445936039, 
0.424538396764547, 0.229595123790205, 0.672923852456734, 0.61330992076546, 
0.374492820119485, 0.583008445333689, 0.94473810470663, 0.25385448615998, 
0.674593120580539, 0.869715234031901, 0.94868006859906, 0.229183854768053, 
0.399804306449369, 0.0552410976961255, 0.153342365752906, 0.20760683552362, 
0.939011836657301, 0.0690710921771824, 0.944459688384086, 0.311271844198927, 
0.795019918819889, 0.935355108231306, 0.559848339296877, 0.160864517092705, 
0.0566015436779708, 0.986112118931487, 0.109344870317727, 0.711717555997893, 
0.168269659625366, 0.967747716465965, 0.0870282740797848, 0.311811906984076, 
0.00380628812126815, 0.677446827525273, 0.949922770261765, 0.596800298895687, 
0.0406050367746502, 0.438798732124269, 0.677494721952826, 0.869463230017573, 
0.954477905295789, 0.728465437423438, 0.0826929600443691, 0.762347809504718, 
0.144062878331169, 0.17963783419691, 0.627232523402199, 0.88223961670883, 
0.0266130077652633, 0.844961556373164, 0.259414804400876, 0.174613558454439, 
0.964706963393837, 0.111714730970562, 0.869064266094938, 0.0844376638997346, 
0.173526355763897, 0.325475359801203, 0.706891416572034, 0.289788722060621, 
0.315327962161973, 0.250811351696029, 0.256510636769235, 0.893950980389491, 
0.702868187101558, 0.1915901475586, 0.883692211238667, 0.596465814160183, 
0.992735084844753, 0.999628762481734, 0.568414112087339, 0.588263624813408, 
0.0249269008636475, 0.27322138636373, 0.464655231451616, 0.449471640633419, 
0.919530394952744, 0.809842582559213, 0.0786217574495822, 0.890167841454968, 
0.617845843313262, 0.521652236580849, 0.522370660211891, 0.591729528969154, 
0.243999561062083, 0.742002451326698, 0.693615336669609, 0.800648423610255, 
0.31477079144679, 0.0315601106267422, 0.563548003323376), TimeE = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TimeI = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Time = c(8, 9, 4, 
9, 4, 6, 3, 4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 
4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4, 
8, 9, 4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4, 8, 
9, 4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 
4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4, 8, 9, 4, 9, 4)), row.names = c(NA, -100L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: at the very end of your code you are using a variable `i` (in`Data$State[i] <-  "Exposed"`).
Should this be a `j`?

Comment: Use `rbinom` to create a column `Data$foo` of `FALSE`/`TRUE` values according to the probability defined by `Urand1 < parameters$S2E`. Then assign `"Exposed"` to the subset defined by the row numbers and `is.TRUE(Data$foo)`. If that is still too slow, work only on the subset defined by the row numbers and join the result back into the whole data.frame afterwards. Or use `data.table` to only work on the subset and avoid that join.

Comment: @Roland Thank you for your comment. What do you mean exactly when you say "the probability defined by `Urand1 < parameters$S2E`. Any chance you would be willing to write it out for me? I notice I am a little bit unfamiliar with these optimisation methods.

Comment: @Cettt I looked at whether it should be `i` or `j`. It should really be `i`, coming from a outer for loop, which I guess makes my post a bit of bad reproducible example.

Comment: The probability is basically `parameters$S2E` (assuming that it is always from the interval [0,1]). The point is that you should replace all these calls to `runif` with one call to the RNG.

Comment: @Roland Ahh I am getting your point now:) Thanks

Comment: @Roland Wait, actually, the runifs are apparently not the problem, `Meetingsa <- Data[People_met[j], ]` is. I'll add the `profvis` output.

Comment: I don't see a reason why a for loop is necessary. But I don't know for sure what the code is supposed to do. It seems we are dealing with a cumulative probability that Data$State[i] is set to "Exposed"? It should be possible to calculate that probability without a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample workflow using `dplyr` which does not use a `for` loop.

```
People_met <- c(15L, 66L)
paramters <- list(S2E = 0.5)

library(dplyr)
set.seed(100)
Data %>% 
  filter(AgentNo %in% People_met) %>% #filter relevant rows
  mutate(
    r_unif = runif(n()), #create random uniform sample 
    State = ifelse(State == "Exposed" & r_unif < paramters$S2E, "Exposed", "Whatelse")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but it actually dramatically increased the time for the function to run (full data is available in the link of my post).